# I am trying to implement Paging 3 into my assignment apps, but the data always not showing

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-paging-3

So there is a problem in my android application, it did not show any data in the recycler view in home fragment, i suspect the problem is in this StoryDataSource because the log for the data fetching is not showing, here is the code

```
class StoryDataSource(private val token: String) : PagingSource<Int, Story>() {

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Story> {
    Log.d("StoryDataSource", "Load method called with params: $params")
    return try {
        val pageNumber = params.key ?: 1
        val storyList = fetchDataFromNetwork(pageNumber)

        LoadResult.Page(
            data = storyList,
            prevKey = if (pageNumber > 1) pageNumber - 1 else null,
            nextKey = if (storyList.isNotEmpty()) pageNumber + 1 else null
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        LoadResult.Error(e)
    }
}

override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Story>): Int? {
    return null
}

private suspend fun fetchDataFromNetwork(pageNumber: Int): List<Story> {
    val client = ApiConfig.getApi().getAllStory("Bearer $token", pageNumber)
    val response = client.execute()

    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        val storyList = response.body()?.listStory ?: emptyList()
        Log.d("StoryDataSource", "Fetched ${storyList.size} stories")
        return storyList
    } else {
        Log.e("StoryDataSource", "Error ${response.code()} : ${response.message()}")
        throw Exception("Error ${response.code()} : ${response.message()}")
    }
}
}
```

the story data source is going to fetch data from the api and the data basically being called in story view model, here is the viewmodel

```
class StoryViewModel(private val pref: Preferences) : ViewModel() {

private val _storyList = MutableStateFlow<PagingData<Story>>(PagingData.empty())
val storyList: StateFlow<PagingData<Story>> = _storyList

private val _error = MutableLiveData<String>()
val error: LiveData<String> = _error

private val _isSuccessUploadStory = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isSuccessUploadStory: LiveData<Boolean> = _isSuccessUploadStory

private val token: LiveData<String> = pref.getUserToken().asLiveData()

init {
    observeToken()
}

private fun observeToken() {
    token.observeForever { tokenValue ->
        if (!tokenValue.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            fetchStoryList(tokenValue)
        }
    }
}

private fun fetchStoryList(token: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val pager = Pager(config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 30)) {
            StoryDataSource(token)
        }
        pager.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope).collect { pagingData ->
            Log.d("StoryViewModel", "Paging data updated: $pagingData")
            _storyList.value = pagingData
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how i show the data to home fragment

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
private val rvAdapter = StoryPagingAdapter()
private lateinit var storyViewModel: StoryViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // Set up RecyclerView
    binding.rvStory.apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        adapter = rvAdapter
    }

    val preferences = Preferences.getInstance((activity as MainActivity).dataStore)

    val viewModelFactory = ViewModelFactory(requireContext(), preferences)

    storyViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)[StoryViewModel::class.java]

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        storyViewModel.storyList.collectLatest { storyList ->
            Log.d("HomeFragment", "Story list updated: $storyList")
            rvAdapter.submitData(storyList)
        }
    }
}
}
```

is there anything wrong with my code

I have alredy write the log for fetching the code, i have already test the rvadapter with mockstorydatasource and it is working, but when using the real data source, it does not shows anything.